# Show that a random vector is not normally distributed although its components are

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X, Y$ be random variables such that $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y = \begin{cases}X &\text{if we throw heads}\\  -X &\text{if we throw tails}\end{cases}$

Show, that even though $Y$ is normally distributed, a random vector $(X,Y)$ is not.

**My solution:**

First part:
$F_Y(y)=\Bbb P(Y \leq y) \overset{\text{Law of total $\Bbb P$}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\Bbb P(X\leq y)+\frac{1}{2}\Bbb P(-X\leq y)=F_X(y)$, so $Y \sim N(0,1)$.

Second part: if a random vector $(X,Y)$ is to be normally distributed, it means that all of linear combinations of its components have to be normally distributed. I need just one example to show that it doesn't hold, so for example a distribution of $X+Y$. But how to do that? What if I assign a value to this expression, let's say $X+Y=0$?

Comment: You don't need the linear combination. You can use the fact that if $X,Y$ are jointly normal then the conditional distribution of $Y|X$ is normal.

Comment: @NeatMath thanks for a reply. But if I really wanted to show it by taking linear combinations? How shall I proceed, I just need one instance when a joint distribution is not normal.

Comment: Yes $X+Y$ will do. Because $\Pr(X+Y=0) = \frac 12$. If it were normally distributed then it must be the degenerated normal distribution, i.e., $N(0,0)$, $X+Y=0, a.s.$, which is not the case.

Comment: @NeatMath thanks a lot. Maybe it's a silly question, but why do we take $X+Y=0$? I mean, why do we pick $0$ instead of any possible value? It is clear to me that we take a specific linear combination $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y \end{pmatrix}$ but why do we check when it is equal to 0 (or any other value)?

Comment: Pick $X+Y=0$ because the way you construct $Y$ is that there's half probability $X+Y=0$. You can also pick $X-Y$.